# Java LocalDateTime.parse with millisecond precision but optional microsecond precision

Tags: java, datetime, parsing

Is there a way to create a LocalDateTime pattern that will parse a date/time that has at least millisecond precision but optional microsecond precision i.e. in the following the millisecond date/time is parsed ok but the second one in microseconds fails. I thought the optional indicators in the pattern "[" "]" would allow this work:

```
DateTimeFormatter DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS[SSS]");
System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse("2019-02-14 11:04:52.784", DATE_TIME_FORMATTER));     
System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse("2019-02-14 11:04:52.784108", DATE_TIME_FORMATTER));
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Hack no. 1

```
    String withMillis = "2019-02-14 11:04:52.784";
    String withMicros = "2019-02-14 11:04:52.784108";

    System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse(withMillis.replace(' ', 'T')));
    System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse(withMicros.replace(' ', 'T')));
```

> ```
> 2019-02-14T11:04:52.784
> 2019-02-14T11:04:52.784108
> ```

When we replace the space in the middle of your string with a `T`, the string conforms to ISO 8601, the standard format that `LocalDateTime` and the other classes of java.time parse (and also print) as their default, that is, without any explicit formatter. So this is an easy solution.

### Hack no. 2

Something like what you tried can be made to work. Only you cannot split a sequence of `SSSSSS` with a square bracket in the middle.

```
static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = 
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.[SSSSSS][SSS]");
```

And then:

```
    System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse(withMillis, DATE_TIME_FORMATTER));     
    System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse(withMicros, DATE_TIME_FORMATTER));
```

I specify optionally 6 decimals and then optionally 3 decimals. We need that order. If we put `[SSS][SSSSSS]` and try to parse 6 decimals, the formatter will first parse 3 and then throw an exception because it cannot parse the remaining 3 with `SSSSSS`. It’s a bit of a hack since it will also accept a decimal point with no decimals at all, and will probably issue a very confusing error message (or possibly even give an incorrect result) if we give it 9 decimals.

### The good solution: use a builder

Edit: I have improved the builder a little since the first version of this answer:

```
static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = 
        new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
                .appendLiteral(' ')
                .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME)
                .toFormatter();
```

`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME` parses from 0 to 9 decimals on the seconds, so we just reuse that formatter in our own formatter.

Original builder:

```
static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = 
        new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
                .appendLiteral(' ')
                .appendPattern("HH:mm:ss")
                .appendFraction(ChronoField.NANO_OF_SECOND, 1, 9, true)
                .toFormatter();
```

Here I have specified a minimum of 1 and a maximum of 9 decimals after the decimal point. You can specify 3 and 6 if you prefer. It will of course accept 4 or 5 too.

**Link:** [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)