# How to convert two different dates in string (2019-12-23 12:40:43.777 and 2019-12-23 12:40:43) to 2019-12-23 format in java 8 in one single method?

Tags: java, datetime, date-formatting, java-time

```
public static void main(String args[]){     
     Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^([0-9]{4}[-][0-9]{2}[-][0-9]{2}\\s+[0-9]{2}[:][0-9]{2}[:][0-9]{2})[.]*([0-9]*)$");
     String mydata = "2019-12-23 12:40:43.775936";//case1
     //String mydata = "2019-12-23 12:40:43";//case2
     Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mydata);
     if(matcher.matches()) {
         System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
     }                                
    DateTimeFormatter dtf  = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse(matcher.group(1), dtf);
    ZonedDateTime     zdt  = date.atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kuwait"));
    System.out.println(zdt.toInstant().toEpochMilli());

}
```

currently, I am doing this by using regex. I want to avoid the use of regex so that my code works for both case 1 and case 2. Please suggest.

Answer (score 3):

No need for regex here, all you need is this pattern

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss[.SSSSSS]
```

Here is a simple example how your code can be :

```
String[] dates  = {"2019-12-23 12:40:43.775936", "2019-12-23 12:40:43"};
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss[.SSSSSS]");
for (String date: dates){
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(date, dtf);
    LocalDate ld = ldt.toLocalDate();
    System.out.println(ld);
}
```

**Outputs**

```
2019-12-23
2019-12-23
```

---

**Edit**

> .. the above code does not work for date in this format : 2019-12-23 12:40:43.888

If you have multiple format, and you are not sure what the date string can look like, then there are other options :

[Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54685730/5558072) suggest a nice trick in his answer, your solution can be like this :

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(date.replace(' ', 'T'));
```

Note that you don't need the `DateTimeFormatter`, because it use the default format of `LocalDateTime`.

Full solution :

```
String[] dates  = {"2019-12-23 12:40:43.775936", "2019-12-23 12:40:43", "2019-12-23 12:40:43.888"};
for (String date: dates){
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(date.replace(' ', 'T'));
    LocalDate ld = ldt.toLocalDate();
    System.out.println(ld);
}
```

---

Another trick, can work in your case, so because you are looking for the date part you can extract it like so :

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse(date.substring(0, date.indexOf(' ')));
```

Full soltion :

```
String[] dates  = {"2019-12-23 12:40:43.775936", "2019-12-23 12:40:43", "2019-12-23 12:40:43.888"};
for (String date: dates){
    LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse(date.substring(0, date.indexOf(' ')));
    System.out.println(ld);
}
```

**Outputs**

```
2019-12-23
2019-12-23
2019-12-23
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment but the above code does not work for date in this format : 2019-12-23 12:40:43.888.

Comment: @priyameshram check my solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single `DateTimeFormatter` having two patterns.

But beware of the order of those patterns, in the following (working) example, the order is the only one that works.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String dateTimeOne = "2019-12-23 12:40:43.775936";
    String dateTimeTwo = "2019-12-23 12:40:43";
    DateTimeFormatter dtf  = DateTimeFormatter
                                .ofPattern("[yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS][yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss]");
    LocalDateTime localDateTimeOne = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeOne, dtf);
    LocalDateTime localDateTimeTwo = LocalDateTime.parse(dateTimeTwo, dtf);
    ZonedDateTime zdtOne  = localDateTimeOne.atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kuwait"));
    ZonedDateTime zdtTwo  = localDateTimeTwo.atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kuwait"));
    System.out.println(zdtOne.toInstant().toEpochMilli());
    System.out.println(zdtTwo.toInstant().toEpochMilli());
}
```

Output:

```
1577094043775
1577094043000
```

I think you should prepare two different `DateTimeFormatter`s and rely on `try`-`catch`, which is ugly, but not as error-prone as this.

**Even better**: Use one of the other answers or have a look at the questions linked in the comments.